# Inline-hint object literal property without coercion?

Tags: typescript, casting, type-hinting

I have a big object literal and the type inference is perfect except one property, which I have to cast:

```
const obj = {
    a: 'big',
    ol: 'object',
    with: 'a lot of properties',
    nums: [] as number[], // would be undefined[] or unknown[] without cast
}
```

This works perfectly well except the `as` irks me and shows up in my linter and my running total-coercion-counter. I can also do `const nums: number[] = []` on a separate line but then I'm using multiple declarations for what's really one object. Writing out the whole interface is unnecessary and verbose. Is there any kind of inline soft-cast or hint so I can get the `: number[]` benefits with the inline-ness of `as`? Angle bracket casts also make my linter angry plus I'm using JSX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for something like a "widening-only assertion" or a "`satisfies` operator" as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#7481](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7481).  The idea is that you'd write something like

```
const obj = {
  a: 'big',
  ol: 'object',
  with: 'a lot of properties',
  nums: [] satisfies number[] // <-- not valid as of TS4.5
}
```

and the compiler would contextually interpret `[]` to be a type assignable to `number[]`, and give an error if it can't.  That would be safer than a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) (which you're calling "casting" or "coercion") which will allow you to unsafely narrow a value to a type.  Currently `"hello" as "goodbye"` is allowed, but `"hello" satisfies "goodbye"` would be an error.

Anyway, there is currently no built-in way to do this in TypeScript.  There *was* a recent design discussion in [microsoft/TypeScript#46872](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/46872) and [microsoft/TypeScript#46878](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/46878), and there's a possible implementation at [microsoft/TypeScript#46827](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/46827).  But it's not clear when this will make it into the language.  For now there are only workarounds.

---

A common workaround is to have a generic helper identity function:

```
const satisfies = <T,>(x: T) => x;
```

And then write `satisfies<Type>(value)` in place of `value satisfies Type`:

```
const obj = {
  a: 'big',
  ol: 'object',
  with: 'a lot of properties',
  nums: satisfies<number[]>([]) // <-- this works
}

/* const obj: {
    a: string;
    ol: string;
    with: string;
    nums: number[];
} */
```

Now the compiler sees `nums` as type `number[]`, as desired.  This version of `satisfies` also gives compiler errors in cases where a type assertion succeeds:

```
"hello" as "goodbye"; // no error
satisfies<"goodbye">("hello") // error!
```

So this workaround is about as good as it gets in current TypeScript.  Yes, it has observable runtime effects since the emitted JavaScript now has an extra function call, but it's a fairly innocuous change.  If you're only going to do such an operation once in your code base, then you might as well write `const nums: number[] = []`.  But if you run into this issue at least twice, then the `satisfies` helper function probably pays for itself.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBBCGUCWEBmSCmEYF4YB4AVAGgD4AKADwC4ZCBKXUmSgbgFgAoL0SWEAEYArXDADeXGDHi0A5AKQBzWcUkwQAGzmChGYFBVqA7kigALOfBgaQ-VDAAOAJxAOMT5FkOcpYAK4AthC0CMhomBD4-gEC7gDaALoUifRcAL5cAPQAVDC80OrCtBI+UtIhUE5IYIocpVKaFVU1dWUwJuZN1bVqvoHBMNGxTol1aTDZmVxcAERmGBo2M9LYM4ogIAAmAgCeGDOsMJmZgyAw7i5OXKEo6Fj4axvbezMUcwtLjMfnTpcAhNNODkYDxwAUdKISlIZDB5EpvA0tLCdHoDKpSh0LLCrDY7I4XG4PBEEYN+rREnBELcIqSYvEEkcTvgALTM06wABu8A0SE2K3U9kIAGUACwAOgArOlJJMgA)

Comment: That workaround is elegant enough in my book. Really appreciate the thorough answer.