# TypeScript: How to create union type from array property on mapped type?

Tags: javascript, typescript, union-types, mapped-types

I am trying to create a union type from the elements of an array in an object that has been annotated to a mapped type. Is it possible to achieve somehow without removing the type annotation?

Example code:

```js
type Persons<Name extends string> = {
    readonly [N in Name]: {
        readonly age: number;
        readonly friends: ReadonlyArray<Name>;
    };
}

type Friends<Name extends string, P extends Persons<Name>, N extends Name> = P[N]["friends"][number]

type Names = 'Bill' | 'Jim' | 'Tom'

// Example with type annotation that I would like to keep
const persons1: Persons<Names> = {
    Bill: {
        age: 40,
        friends: ['Jim']
    },
    Jim: {
        age: 42,
        friends: ['Tom']
    },
    Tom: {
        age: 45,
        friends: []
    }
}

// Example without type annotation (for which it works as expected)
const persons2 = {
    Bill: {
        age: 40,
        friends: ['Jim']
    },
    Jim: {
        age: 42,
        friends: ['Tom']
    },
    Tom: {
        age: 45,
        friends: []
    }
} as const

type Friends1 = Friends<Names, typeof persons1, 'Jim'>
// 'Jim' | 'Bill' | 'Tom' - would like it to be 'Tom'

type Friends2 = Friends<Names, typeof persons2, 'Jim'>
// 'Tom' - as wanted
```

My guess was that it could be done by deep cloning persons1 but haven't been able to get the correct type of the clone.

Comment: "without removing the type annotation?" <-- why do you care or need this?  If you annotate a variable with a non-union type, you are telling the compiler the type of the variable and assignments will not change this.  Assignments do narrow variables of union types, but that's not what you have here.  There is no way to "deep clone" persons1 at the type level; sounds like you're confusing runtime and compile time.   If you know how to get it to work (no annotation and adding `as const` to hint that you want narrow types), what is the problem with that method?

Comment: For context I'm intending to use this in a module where the object that conforms to the mapped type is a sort of a config-object that will be declared literally and not fetched dynamically. 

The idea was to both make use of the warnings and auto-completion and so on that comes with annotation and to narrow the return type for a function that takes the object as input based on the values in the object. Technically it works as is and I can achieve one of the two but would create a better developer experience to get both somehow.

Comment: If I skip annotation and add "as const" to the config-object, I can at least get warnings (if it does not conform to the mapped type) from the function that takes the object as input.

Are there other, better ways of doing this that I'm not seeing?

Comment: What you really want is the so-called `satisfies` operator; current workarounds are to make a helper identity function.  Essentially https://stackoverflow.com/a/70582466/2887218 .  Does that answer help you?

Comment: Interesting idea - played around with it a little bit and think I've found a couple of ways it could be used to accomplish what I wanted (or at least close enough). Thank you!